# Inheriting a contract to match state layout in a delegatecall

Tags: solidity, evm, delegatecall, inheritance

What is the best way to manage the state layout of a contract will exclusively be used via a `delegatecall`?

Let's say that there is a `Parent` contract that uses `delegatecall` on a `Child` contract. Within this call, the `Child` contract modifies some state within the `Parent` contract.

There are two possibilities I am considering:

1. Copy and paste the `Parent`'s state layout into the `Child` contract. This is cumbersome if there are many `Child` contracts and the `Parent`'s state layout changes during development.
2. Extend the Parent contract in the Child's contract (e.g. `contract Child is Parent {...}`). This allows the Child contract to reference state from the Parent contract at build time, but it isn't clear that the Child's state layout will exactly match its Parent contract.

As a result, I was curious if using `contract Child is Parent {...}` is a valid way to import the state layout for this purpose. It would make development much simpler - if I made a change to the `Parent` contract, the changes would automatically cascade down to all of the contracts that extended the `Parent`.

Note that for the purpose of this, the Child contracts will store a variable called `parent` which allows them to verify that they are being used by the intended caller.

Comment: Just create a storage file, and inherit that file to all child contracts.